# Display Resource Name in Event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying out the new Scheduler add-on for [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io%20Fullcalendar). I've got it all working great, but I hoped there'd be a property I could add to an Event object so that it would display the name of the Resource it's associated with as well as the Title, but there doesn't seem to be. Is there a way in which this could be done?

The goal is for Events displayed in a standard calendar view (e.g. agendaWeek) to show the time and Title (as they do now) as well as the Resource Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough to do with the [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback.

```
eventRender:function( event, element, view ) {
    $(element).find(".fc-content").append("<div>"+event.resourceId+"</div>");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/u2fL05ea/7/)

If you want, say the title of the resource instead of the ID, use the [`getResourceById`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/getResourceById/) method too.

```
eventRender:function( event, element, view ) {
    var resource = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getResourceById","1");
    $(element).find(".fc-content").append("<div>"+resource.title+"</div>");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/u2fL05ea/8/)