# How can I display both event name and resource name in list view?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using the Scheduler with draggable external events. The list views would be handy for some people, but right now only event name is listed (I've been looking at listWeek). How can I show both the event name followed by the resource name on the same line?

I found one other post on a similar topic, but the second example showing the resource title doesn't work (the title is undefined when I try it):

[Display Resource Name in Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136762/display-resource-name-in-event)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the first example, but instead of appending the divs onto `.fc-content`, you want to append it onto `.fc-list-item-title` since that is the element used in list view.

like so:

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        $(element).find(".fc-list-item-title").append("<div>" + event.resourceId + "</div>");
    }
```

It will put the resource ID as a new line under the event title.

I'm not sure how to use the second method which gets the title of the resource rather than the ID, but for now, you can set the resource ID to match the resource title or add a different property to your events and append that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to get the Title of the resource in list view.

```
    eventRender:function( event, element, view ) {
    var resourceTitle = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getResourceById",event.resourceId);
    $(element).find(".fc-list-item-title").append("<div>"+resourceTitle.title+"</div>");
}
```

Don't forget to put the comma in the end on the row above when adding this.

Good luck!